# How to check if a shell command executed properly or not?

Tags: linux, unix, shell, tar

```
#!/bin/sh
tar=$1
if [ -f $tar ]
then
    tar xvf $tar
else
    exit 1
fi

... <more code>
```

I need a conformation that the tar actually happened successfully, otherwise abort the execution of the script.

The tar file extract might not go through because

- some problems with `tar` command
- access issues with `$tar`

Do Linux utilities have some return values? How should I use them here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the `$?` variable after executing a command. If everything is OK, it should be `0`, positive otherwise.

```
tar xvf $tar
[ $? -ne 0 ] && exit 1
```

More information [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html).

Comment: `$?` or `$&`? Also, where can I read more about these syntax elements (`$?` etc)?

Comment: Sorry, `$?`. Thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 3):

This

```
tar xvf "$tar" || exit 1
```

or this (if you want to check if file exists yourself)

```
[ -f "$tar" ] && tar xvf "$tar" || exit 1
```